# INDEX MATCH repeats last valid result

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I've searched for this issue and I've found some that were close, but not quite, so forgive me if it has been asked and answered.

When using INDEX/MATCH, all my results are correct, except that the final valid result is returning/repeating where there is no match.

This....

```
=INDEX('Vista Point'!$F$9:$F$34,MATCH(B33,'Vista Point'!$D$9:$D$34,6))
=INDEX('Vista Point'!$F$9:$F$34,MATCH(B34,'Vista Point'!$D$9:$D$34,6))
=INDEX('Vista Point'!$F$9:$F$34,MATCH(B35,'Vista Point'!$D$9:$D$34,6))
=INDEX('Vista Point'!$F$9:$F$34,MATCH(B36,'Vista Point'!$D$9:$D$34,6))
```

Produces this...
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3py5b.png

Even though the last 2 cells are not even in the search array...
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2WQ8c.png

I'm sure it's obvious to you, but I'm just not seeing the problem

Comment: The match type parameter (where your 6 is) of Match should probaably be `0` for exact match. You might switch to `XMATCH` to deal with the no match condition.